Journal I published is on the ESCI list, but can't find it in PubMed, is there a reason for that?
I recently authored a simple case report in a local journal. It is Q4 in Scimago and in the ESCI of Clarivate. But I can't find my paper in Pubmed. Is there a reason for that?

ESCI is not the same as PubMed. I don't think there's a reason to expect ESCI journals to be indexed by PubMed.

Here's a page that tells you what PubMed indexes:
https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/about/

MEDLINE MEDLINE is the largest component of PubMed and consists
primarily of citations from journals selected for MEDLINE; articles
indexed with MeSH (Medical Subject Headings) and curated with funding,
genetic, chemical and other metadata.
PubMed Central (PMC) Citations for PubMed Central (PMC) articles make
up the second largest component of PubMed.
PMC is a full text archive that includes articles from journals
reviewed and selected by NLM for archiving (current and historical),
as well as individual articles collected for archiving in compliance
with funder policies.
Bookshelf The final component of PubMed is citations for books and
some individual chapters available on Bookshelf.
Bookshelf is a full text archive of books, reports, databases, and
other documents related to biomedical, health, and life sciences.

Also more detail about what it takes for MEDLINE including criteria and how to apply at https://www.nlm.nih.gov/medline/medline_home.html
Scimago and Clarivate aren't listed as relevant in deciding what PubMed indexes. A "Q4" journal is not very well regarded and I'm not that surprised it isn't included. If you search PubMed for the journal title you'll probably find no articles are indexed, not just yours.

Thank you. While they are not relevant, I assumed they have similar guidelines for what they include in their archives. I know a Q4 journal is not well regarded, but it is nearly impossible to publish a case report without paying an exorbitant amount for a respected journal.

@BilalBahadırAkbulut I don't think their guidelines are very similar. That said there's still a lot of junk in PubMed.

True that. For some reason, I keep thinking PubMed is this archive that accepts everything (like Google Scholar), while WoS and Scopus vet their journals. I guess I was wrong on that account.

@ Bilal Bahadir Akbulut : One can publish a case report in well regarded subscription-based journals, depending on the specialty of course. You may have to modify your manuscript in some ways (e.g. to comply with special sections (e.g. see AJM)). There are some case report-specific journals that charge less than 1000$, and I am not talking about Hindawi / MDPI / etc ;)
